# Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css

I'm writting script to hide/show menu but I get some troubles.

```
    function displayMenu() {
//var classMenu = event.target.className;
//classMenu += 'Menu';
    //document.getElementsByClassName(classMenu).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-pageMenu').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

In comment what I want to do finally, but even if I try with static var it's not working.
In the CSS :

```
    fieldset.toolsbox ul.btn-pageMenu {display:none;}
```

I try like this too :

```
    .btn-pageMenu {display:none;}
```

No more success. Anybody have a suggestion ? I'm learning JS and I not finding errors when I compare with other similar scripts.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery for hide and show ? But anyways make sure you are targeting it the right way. does your element really have the class of "btn-pageMenu" or maybe there is an ID which you could use ?

Comment: Because i prefer make my own JS script than use a full library just for some features. And yes i'm sure to use class.

Comment: @TikTaZ: FYI `fieldset.toolsbox ul#btn-pageMenu {display:none;}` in your css would enable the use of `getElementById('btn-pageMenu')`, or `document.querySelector('#btn-pageMenu')`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('btn-pageMenu')` delivers a [nodeList](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/NodeList). You should use: `document.getElementsByClassName('btn-pageMenu')[0].style.display` (if it's the first element from that list you want to change.

If you want to change `style.display` for all nodes loop through the list:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-pageMenu');
for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i+=1){
  elems[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

to be complete: if you use jquery it is as simple as:

```
​$('.btn-pageMenu').css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'block');​​​​​​
```

Comment: Oh sorry to waste your time, in my mind as i specify a unic className i thinked it will find as ID, forget that class can be mutiple so it return a list. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Hi @TikTaz, answering a question is rarely a waste of time. I think other people can benefit from answers too.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this answer in the site https://plainjs.com/javascript/styles/set-and-get-css-styles-of-elements-53/.

In this code we add multiple styles in an element:

```js
let
    element = document.querySelector('span')
  , cssStyle = (el, styles) => {
      for (var property in styles) {
          el.style[property] = styles[property];
      }
  }
;

cssStyle(element, { background:'tomato', color: 'white', padding: '0.5rem 1rem'});
```

```css
span{
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #323232;
background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span>
lorem ipsum
</span>
```