# Unable to display Form element after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

#### Problem:

I'm trying to implement a dropdown form from a button. However, I'm having issues with the form not staying visible even after the condition is met. I'm new to javascript and css, so bear with me if it's a silly error. Thanks in advance.

---

#### What I want to do:

> 1. The form will be hidden by default.
> 2. When a user hovers over an image button, the form should be shown and hidden after the mouseleave.
> 3. If the user clicks the button, then the form should stay visible so that the user can enter the data and sumbit it.

---

#### Observation:

> 1. The objectives #1 and #2 from above are working as expected.
> 2. As opposed to objective #3, the form automatically hides even after the button click.

---

#### Unsuccessful Methods:

> 1. Using `.show()` instead of `.css("display","block")`
> 2. Using `form:hover` to set `display:block`.
> 3. Using `setTimeout(hide_function,500)` hides the form after 500ms regardless of the button click.

---

#### Code:

Here's the link to my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3h8gvek/) that you can use to test it out.

---

#### References:

> 1. For [button click detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081608/jquery-check-if-it-is-clicked-or-not).
> 2. For [changing display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194435/cannot-set-property-display-of-undefined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have modified your code little bit please check with the fiddle

```
$('#dropbtn').click(function() {
  $(this).data('clicked', 'yes');
  $('#loginForm').addClass('activate');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d3h8gvek/7/

Answer (score 1):

Just change data attr:

```
 $('#dropbtn').click(function() {
  $(this).data('clicked', 'yes');
  $('#loginForm').css('display', 'block');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d3h8gvek/3/#run //fixed result