# How can I hide a div until a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create 3 divs that are hidden when the page load, so that when I click their respective buttons they show up, however, no matter what I do, I cannot get them to show up with the button click.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

My div and button:

```
<button onclick="TestsFunction()">Tests</button>

<div id="TestsDiv" style="display:none">
    tests here!
</div>
```

And the JS used to show it:

```
function TestsFunction() {
    var T = document.getElementById("TestsDiv");
    T.style.display = "none";}
```

I can successfully hide the div when I load the page, however after I click the button it doesn't show up again.

I tried

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('TestsDiv').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Instead of style="display:none" on the div to see if the way I hid it was the problem, but the div still wouldn't show up.

I'm a beginner and I'm not good with JS, HTML or PHP, if possible can someone both help and explain my mistake? Do I need something else in my code? I tried reading similar threads but the solutions were all too complicated for my understanding and I ended up not being able to fix my problem. Thank you!

Comment: `T.style.display = "none";` should be `T.style.display = "";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set display to `block` (or something else) but not `hide` when button is clicked!

```js
function TestsFunction() {
    var T = document.getElementById("TestsDiv");
    T.style.display = "block";  // <-- Set it to block
}
```

```html
<button onclick="TestsFunction()">Tests</button>

<div id="TestsDiv" style="display:none">
    tests here!
</div>
```

Comment: I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')**

Comment: For some reason this worked: Instead of Id I made it a class and then added this to the function: `document.getElementsByClassName('TestsDiv')[0].style.display='block';`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194435/cannot-set-property-display-of-undefined

Comment: There has to be a typo in your code with the id. Or maybe you have the same id twice in your HTML. There should not be a difference between id and class (except for the selector ofc) @AnonymousUser

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt your function to *toggle* the display of the div. Currently it is only hiding it - but if its already hidden, remove the `display = "none"` to show it again. You remove it by setting the `display` style to an empty string (which makes it default).

```js
function TestsFunction() {
    var T = document.getElementById("TestsDiv"),
        displayValue = "";
    if (T.style.display == "")
        displayValue = "none";

    T.style.display = displayValue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="TestsFunction()">Tests</button>

<div id="TestsDiv" style="display:none">
    tests here!
</div>
```

If you only want it to be shown, and not to be able toggle display on and off, just set it to the empty string right away.

```js
function TestsFunction() {
    document.getElementById("TestsDiv").style.display = "";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="TestsFunction()">Tests</button>

<div id="TestsDiv" style="display:none">
    tests here!
</div>
```

Comment: Because I only want the button to show them after I click them, I feel there's no reason to toggle. My objective is that the user doesn't need to re-click to hide it, and just click on another of the buttons. I found that for my case what was wrong was using **display = "none"** instead of **display = "block"** in the function. I will consider the toggle option for settings if I include them, though, thank you!

Comment: Alright, fair enough! :-) As long as you got what you needed! You don't need to set `display = "block"`, you can simply set it to the default value by setting the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function TestsFunction() { TestsDiv.style.display = 'block' }
```

```js
function TestsFunction() { TestsDiv.style.display = 'block' }
```

```html
<button onclick="TestsFunction()">Tests</button>

<div id="TestsDiv" style="display:none">
    tests here!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into jQuery's hide() and show() methods. They take care of setting the styles for you.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0):

do like this =>

```
function TestsFunction(){
$("#TestsDiv").css("display","block")
}
```

before that you should include jquery cdn.
thank you.

Comment: This works, but including jQuery just for messing with some CSS is unnecessary

Comment: function TestsFunction() {
  document.getElementById("TestsDiv").style.display="block";
}

you can try this..if this answer works please mark as correct answer..thank you